# Invoking a method on a generic contravariant interface

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, casting

I have this interface:

```
interface IHandler
{
    Type Type { get; } // returns typeof(T).
}

interface IHandler<in T> : IHandler
    where T : IEvent
{
    void Invoke(T ev);
}
```

Then I have a function which is supposed to call all `Handler<T>.Invoke(T)` which accept `ev.GetType()` (That's what `GetHandlersFor(Type)` does). However, I can't figure out how to call the `Invoke` method:

```
    public void Invoke(IEvent ev)
    {
        ImmutableArray<IHandler> selected;
        lock (_listeners)
        {
            selected = GetHandlersFor(ev.GetType()).ToImmutableArray();
        }

        // first attempt
        foreach (var tl in selected)
        {
            Debug.Assert(tl.Type.IsInstanceOfType(ev)); // my data structure invariant
            ((IHandler<IEvent>) tl).Invoke(ev); // InvalidCastException
        }

        // second attempt
        foreach (dynamic tl in selected)
        {
            tl.Invoke(ev); // RuntimeBinderException
        }
    }
```

In the first attempt I get an `` System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'MyHandler`1[ChatEvent]' to type 'IHandler`1[IEvent]'.' ``

In the second attempt I get an `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''object' does not contain a definition for 'Invoke''.`.

My debugger shows me type of `tl` to be `MyHandler<ChatEvent>` and type of `ev` to be `ChatEvent`. In case you wonder, MyHandler is defined as `class MyHandler<T> : IHandler<T> where T : IEvent { ... }`.

How do I invoke my handlers?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: You're trying to do covariant casting on something that is contravariant.  With contravariance you can only cast from less derived to more derived because you pass that type in (the item passed in can be more derived and still work).  Likely what you need to do is also make the code that is calling this generic as well, or overload the method with the different expected types.  I mean your `t1` can only handle `ChatEvent` and you don't want to pass it other implementation of `IEvent` do you?

Comment: The simplest way would be to avoid doing this at all. Can you just provide a non-generic interface and have your classes implement both, similar to how BCL `List<T>` implements both `IList<T>` and `IList`? That means adding `Invoke(object ev)` to `IHandler`, which will throw an exception if the argument is of the wrong type.

Comment: @juharr Yeah, I *know* it's okay because I only do that to call `Invoke` with an argument of a fitting type (see the Debug.Assert line). And I know the type too, but only in the form of `Type`. If only there was something like the inverse of `typeof(T)` :P. I went with hvd's solution..